# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-room 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: reactjs

I have been working on a web app with django rest framework for backend and react js for front end.

```
 handleRoomButtonClicked() {
    console.log(this.state)
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            votes_to_skip: this.state.votesToSkip,
            guest_can_pause: this.state.guestCanPause,

        }),
    };
    fetch("/api/create-room", requestOptions).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => console.log(data));

}
```

I am getting an error at the fetch part , please someone help

Answer (score 0):

First hint: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` in your request header, do nothing!
it should be sent from the back-end, don't try to bypass the CORS like that.

Quoted from MDN:

> The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates
> that the  server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

This means your end-point needs authorization and you have to some credentials with your request.

Comment: Hey, I did this yesterday but didnt get any error. What I am trying to do here is I have page where I make a room by taking some inputs like : votes to skip , guestcanpause,etc , when I click on the create button it should send a request to the api/create-room with the payload  'requestOptions' and once we get a response I printing the data from the response on the console log !  What should I do ?

Comment: Problem Solved. It was giving an error because I was logged into django admin page, when I logged out, it worked!